# Ride-sharing in Sweden?

Tags: sweden, ride-sharing

Is there a popular website for arranging ride-sharing in Sweden?   In Germany I've had good luck with carpooling.com / mitfahrgelegenheit.de, but that site doesn't seem to get much use in Sweden.

Is there another, more popular website for arranging ride-sharing in Sweden?

Comment: When I searched for ride-sharing in Norway I finally found a Facebook group for a particular region that was vastly more popular than the national website. So it might depend on the region of Sweden — it's a big country.

Answer (score 5):

I found one Sweden-specific ride-sharing site:

- http://www.samakning.se/

Not sure how popular it is.

(*Samåkning* basically means "ride sharing" in Swedish.)

Comment: Link is currently dead ("Down for maintenance") not sure for how long

Answer (score 5):

There's [skjutsgruppen](http://skjutsgruppen.nu/), which is quite popular. The site is in Swedish, but google translate gives a reasonable translation.

Comment: Since 2018 this service is only available via an app that you download at the website.

Comment: And the app needs a rediculous ammount of invasive permissions. Contains 6 trackers. Bit much for a simple rideshare application. https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/reports/37199/